# OpenCL method get_global_id() works incorrectly on GPU

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

I want to parallelize temperatures distribution, using OpenCL technology. I stocked on problem with my GPU - work item id for every other kernel function are the same. Instead of result, for example, from 0 to 1024, I got this result. What I did incorrectcly?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3uAf.png)

Source.cpp

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <omp.h>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

float*** distributeOpenCL(float*** cuboid, int k, int m, int n)
{
    // OpenCL init
    int size = k * m * n;
    float*** hResult = initCuboid(k, m, n);
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_int error = 0;
    std::ifstream file("program.cl");
    std::string fileText = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    const char* srcText = fileText.data();
    size_t srcLength = fileText.size();
    cl_context context;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_mem dCuboid, dRes;
    size_t localSize[2] = { k,m };
    size_t globalSize[2] = { ceil(size / (float)localSize[0]) * localSize[0], ceil(size / (float)localSize[1]) * localSize[1] };
    // Get GPU
    error |= clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    error |= clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);
    // Compile and build
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &error);
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &srcText, &srcLength, &error);
    error |= clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // What funtion from file we have to run
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "distributeKernel", &error);
    // Add to Queue
    queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device, NULL, &error);
    // Create buffer
    dCuboid = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * size, NULL, NULL);
    dRes = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * size, NULL, NULL);
    // Write data to buffer
    error |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, dCuboid, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * size, cuboid, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // Kernel args
    error |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &dCuboid);
    error |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(int), &k);
    error |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(int), &m);
    error |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(int), &n);
    error |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), &dRes);
    // Start task
    error |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalSize, localSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // Wait execution
    clFinish(queue);
    // Read Result
    error |= clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, dRes, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * size, hResult, 0, NULL, NULL);
    //printCuboid(resP, k, m, n, resPFile);
    // Deallocation
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseMemObject(dCuboid);
    clReleaseMemObject(dRes);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseContext(context);
    return hResult;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream filledFile("filled.txt");
    std::ofstream resLFile("resL.txt");
    std::ofstream resPFile("resP.txt");
    double durationL, durationP, time1, time2;
    int k = 5, m = 5, n = 5, temp1 = 10, temp2 = 15;
    float*** cuboid, *** resL, *** resP;
    if (argc > 1) {
        k = atoi(argv[1]), m = atoi(argv[2]), n = atoi(argv[3]),
            temp1 = atoi(argv[4]), temp2 = atoi(argv[5]);
    }
    // Linear
    cuboid = initCuboid(k, m, n);
    fillCuboid(cuboid, k, m, n, temp1, temp2);
    printCuboidToFile(cuboid, k, m, n, filledFile);
    time1 = omp_get_wtime();
    resL = distribute(cuboid, k, m, n);
    time2 = omp_get_wtime();
    durationL = time2 - time1;
    printCuboidToFile(resL, k, m, n, resLFile);
    // Parallel
    time1 = omp_get_wtime();
    resP = distributeOpenCL(cuboid, k, m, n);
    time2 = omp_get_wtime();
    durationP = time2 - time1;
    //printCuboidToFile(resP, k, m, n, resPFile);
    std::cout << "Linear time: " << durationL << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Parallel time: " << durationP << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Parallel faster than linear on: " << durationL - durationP << std::endl;
    // Delete 3d arrays, closing files
    deleteCuboid(cuboid, k, m, n);
    deleteCuboid(resL, k, m, n);
    deleteCuboid(resP, k, m, n);
    filledFile.close();
    resLFile.close(); 
    resPFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

program.cl

```
__kernel void distributeKernel(__global float*** cuboid, int k, int m, int n, __global float*** result)
{
    int gz = get_global_id(0);
    int gy = get_global_id(1);
    printf("gy - %d \n", &gy);
    printf("gz - %d \n", &gz);
        bool isDissipated = false;
    int size = k * m * n;
    // Ends if temperatures in cube becomes balanced
    while (!isDissipated) {
        int dissipatedCount = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            // Calc average temperature
            float sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            float average;
            for (int zSum = gz - 1; zSum <= gz + 1; zSum++) {
                for (int ySum = gy - 1; ySum <= gy + 1; ySum++) {
                    for (int xSum = x - 1; xSum <= x + 1; xSum++) {
                        if (zSum >= 0 && ySum >= 0 && xSum >= 0
                            && zSum < k && ySum < m && xSum < n) {
                            count++;
                            sum += result[gz][gy][xSum];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            average = round(sum / count * 100) / 100;
            if (average == result[gz][gy][x]) {
                dissipatedCount++;
            }
            else {
                result[gz][gy][x] = average;
            }
        }
        if (dissipatedCount == size) {
            isDissipated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the issue with the supposedly wrong `get_global_id()` fixed, start with a simple, minimal "Hello World"-style vector addition program and than advance forward to your temperature distribution application step-by-step.

With your code I see several issues:

1. You can only have 1D pointers (with a single `*`) in OpenCL.

   ```c
   __kernel void distributeKernel(__global float* cuboid, __global float* result)
   ```

   Introduce a linear index to access more than 1 dimension: For 2D for example `int n = x+y*get_global_size(0);`
2. From what I see, `k`, `m`, `n` are lattice dimensions. Eliminate them from the kernel entirely. Get `size` via `get_global_size(...)`.
3. The kernel looks rather complex with a lot of loops and branching. This could kill any performance benefit you hope to get from GPU parallelization. Get rid of loops and branching as far as possible. Also, there should not be any loop over one of the lattice dimensions since the lattice position is what you parallelize.

I would also advice to use only 1D parallelization in OpenCL and do the linear indexing yourself. This gives you more flexibility regarding workgroup size.